How to decompose invertible elements into positive and unitary elements in C$^*$-algebras?
I have to proof that if $X$ is a C$^*$-algebra and $x\in X$ is invertible, there exist an hermitean $y\in X$ and an $u\in X^+$ such that $x=yu$. If $x$ is normal, I found this decompositian using functional calculus, but how do I proof this for a possibly non-normal but invertible element of $X$?
I tried using something like $x=(xx^*)(x^*)^{-1}$ and $xx^*$ is obviously normal, but that doesn't seem to work.

Look up "polar decomposition".

$x = (x|x|^{-1})|x|$.

(I assumed you meant $y$ to be unitary or normal instead of Hermitian. The claim is false if $y$ needs to be Hermitian.)

As stated, this is false, even for normal $x$. If $y$ is Hermitian and $u$ is positive, then $yu$ has real spectrum (because $\sigma(yu)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(u^{1/2}yu^{1/2})\cup\{0\}$). So any invertible $x$ with non-real spectrum will fail the assertion. For instance $x=i$.
If instead you look for something like the polar decomposition, where $y$ is a partial isometry, the natural choice is to take $u=|x|$. This $u$ will be invertible if $x$ is, so it forces $y=x|x|^{-1}$. This $y$ is a unitary.
